# Quiloader not loading ui file

Tags: qt

I am trying a simple code to load a ui file runtime, but not able to load it.

```
QUiLoader loader;
QFile file(":/dialog.ui");
file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QWidget *myWidget = loader.load(&file, this);
file.close();
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(myWidget);
setLayout(layout);
```

I have added the dialog.ui file in my .qrc file as well as mentioned [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.3/quiloader.html)  . Not getting any error message. Please tell me what has gone wrong.

Regards

Comment: I'd check the return value of file.open().

Comment: The value of file.open is 1. Also 1 more thing is I am getting value of file as <not available> in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it.. Here's the code.

```
QUiLoader uiLoader;
QFile file(":/dialog.ui");
QWidget *sortDialog = uiLoader.load(&file);
if (sortDialog) {
    sortDialog->show();
}
```